# How to save changes in Plain Text Content Control in docx file using python

Tags: python, docx, word-contentcontrol, documentfile

We have a docx files, which contains content control tags, want to replace those with other tags using python as numbers of files is more.
How to save changes in Plain Text Content Control in docx file using python or R.

How to save changes in Plain Text Content Control in docx file using python or R.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Used python docx, docx_form libraries I can about to read it but changes are not getting saved. https://pypi.org/project/docx-form/